# Configuration error. Class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] not found. EclipseLink, MySQL driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to learn JPA using EclipseLink. I am using Mysql as my DB. I have added the all the dependencies required and below is my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The issue is that even though maven has downloaded all the required jars for mysql jdbc connector I am getting Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] not found. Following are the version I am using:
1. Mysql JDBC connector : 8.0.11
2. Eclipselink: 2.7.1
3. JPA: 2.2.0

Attached is the screenshot of my Maven dependencies jars.

I tried all the suggestions from other threads on stackoverflow but couldn't resolve the issue.

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance !

Below is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

   <persistence-unit name="Eclipselink_JPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

      <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpadb"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
      </properties>

   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Also, adding the error stack trace:

[EL Fine]: server: 2018-06-24 17:33:10.619--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Configured server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform
[EL Info]: 2018-06-24 17:33:11.065--ServerSession(1101598632)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2018-06-24 17:33:11.068--ServerSession(1101598632)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] not found.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at practice.JPA.persistence.App.main(App.java:17)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.configurationErrorClassNotFound(DatabaseException.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.loadDriverClass(DefaultConnector.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:734)
    ... 5 more

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace as well as the configuration xml for EclipseLink?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am using JavaSE 1.8

Comment: Added persistence.xml to the question

Comment: What server are you using to deploy to?

Answer (score 0):

My project uses MySQL with EclipseLink implementation of JPA, and works fine. My pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i'm too late, but may help anyone.
In my case i'm using mysql-connector-java3.1.11 and get the same error. After trying some other solutions that didn't work, i've checked the source code of "persistence.xml" and changed the following line:
`<property name="javax.persistence.cj.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>`
to
`<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>`
(removing "cj" from the string)
After that i got the program run without problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).